# How to annotate a changed item in a listbox with a *

Tags: c#

I just need help on how to annotate a changed item in the list box if the user changes something using the text boxes provided.

```
namespace HW1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] values = new string[5];
            values[0] = textBox1.Text;
            values[1] = textBox2.Text;
            values[2] = textBox3.Text;
            values[3] = textBox4.Text;
            values[4] = textBox5.Text;

            string[] temp = new string[5];
            temp[0] = textBox1.Text;
            temp[1] = textBox2.Text;
            temp[2] = textBox3.Text;
            temp[3] = textBox4.Text;
            temp[4] = textBox5.Text;

            if(temp != values)
            {
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 + "*";
                listBox1.Text = values[1] + "*";
                listBox1.Text = values[2] + "*";
                listBox1.Text = values[3] + "*";
                listBox1.Text = values[4] + "*";
            }


            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(values[i].ToString());
            }

        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

The program will simply replace the old input from the text box with the new without displaying a * next to the item that has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't actually compile... not sure how this line would ever work...
`listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 + "*";`

Anyway - the main problem is that your for loop adds in values without the star to the list box

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
   listBox1.Items.Add(values[i].ToString());  //values[i] never has a star stored in it!
}
```

How about something like this...?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] values = new [] { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text };

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                if (listBox1.Items.Count < i + 1)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(values[i].ToString());
                    continue;
                }
                string unedited = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(unedited) && unedited.Last() == '*')
                    unedited = listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Substring(0, listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Length - 1);

                if (unedited != values[i])
                    listBox1.Items[i] = values[i] + "*";
                else
                    listBox1.Items[i] = values[i];
            }

        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

This compares the list items to the textbox values.
If the textbox value doesn't exist, a listbox item is created.
If the listbox item doesn't match the textbox value, it has a `*` appended to it.
If an existing value (ignoring the star) is the same as the textbox value, it is updated to ensure the star is removed.